# Замена элементов массива на новые PHP

Tags: php

У меня есть такой массив:

```
    $res = Array( [1] => - [2] => suhovv64@yandex.ru, to-nn@mail.ru 
    [3] => - [4] => itorgipsv@mail.ru [5] => to-nn@mail.ru [6] => - )
```

хочу вместо дефиса "-" поставить " ".
Подскажите, как сделать что получился такой массив?

```
$res = Array( [1] => ' ' [2] => suhovv64@yandex.ru, to-nn@mail.ru 
    [3] => ' ' [4] => itorgipsv@mail.ru [5] => to-nn@mail.ru [6] => ' ' )
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Пробегаемся обычным циклом `for` со счётчиком `$i` от 0 до `count($res)`
2. Пишем условие (`if`) если символ в элементе под индексом `$i` равен дефису, то заменить на пробел (присвоить этому элементу значение "пробел").
3. PROFIT

---

Кстати, подобное действие проще делать уже в шаблоне, при выводе пользователю, т.к. там даже не придётся заменять одно значение массива на другое, а сразу можно выводить пустоту, если значение является дефисом

Comment: Только начал изучать PHP. можете показать пример?

Comment: Это слишком базовая база, чтобы показывать пример. Прочтите книгу для новичков раздел циклы, условные операторы и массивы. Вам же самому надо потом всё это правильно написать. Алгоритм выше. Всё, что надо - один в один слова перевести в код